# Access Glue Catalog from Dev endpoint and local Zeppelin with spark sql

Tags: amazon-emr, aws-glue

I have set up a local Zeppelin notebook to access Glue Dev endpoint. I'm able to run spark and pyspark code and access the Glue catalog. But when I try `spark.sql("show databases").show()` or `%sql show databases` only ***default*** is returned.

When spinning up an EMR cluster we have to choose "***Use for Hive table metadata***" to enable this, but I hoped this would be the default setting for Glue Development endpoint, which seems to be not the case. Any workaround for this?